# Interesting property of Pascal's Triangle

Tags: combinatorics

I was looking at the Pascal's Triangle and saw that for all central numbers in **even** length row $a \gt 17$, the number $\dbinom{a}{b-2}$ is greater than $\dbinom{a-1}{b}$. This is where $b$ is equal to $(a-1)/2$.

For example, in this image of the Triangle, 
[image]

For example, let us take the number $48620$. This is the central element of the $19^{th}$ row.

$\dbinom{19}{7}=50388$ (in row $20$) is greater than $\dbinom{18}{9}=48620$.

Can somebody please help me prove this?

Comment: A small illustrating example of what you mean would be extremely useful here.

Comment: I've edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to prove that 
$$\binom{n+1}{\frac n2-2}\gt\binom{n}{\frac n2}$$
holds for every even $n\ge 18$.
(your example is the case for $n=18$.)

Let $n=2m$. Then, we have
$$\begin{align}\binom{2m+1}{m-2}-\binom{2m}{m}&=\frac{(2m+1)!}{(m+3)!(m-2)!}-\frac{(2m)!}{m!m!}\\&=\frac{(2m)!}{m!(m+3)!}\left((2m+1)m(m-1)-(m+3)(m+2)(m+1)\right)\\&=\frac{(2m)!}{m!(m+3)!}(m^3-7 m^2-12 m-6)\\&=\frac{(2m)!}{m!(m+3)!}(m(m(m-7)-12)-6)\end{align}$$

Now it is easy to see that this is positive for $m\ge 9$.

Hence, we can say that $$\binom{n+1}{\frac n2-2}\gt\binom{n}{\frac n2}$$
holds for every even $n\ge 18$.

Comment: Perhaps it would have been better to simply divide them, and then inspect under what circumstances is their ratio $>1$.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks!